# Batch Scripting-Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am new to python, I am creating an application which requires multiple batch files to be generated. There are only few minor differences in every batch files. Is there any way i can create a batch file using code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can**

A Batch file is just a normal text file, which is executable. In order to get the File executable, you need to:

1. Set File permissions, (On Linux via chmod +x)
2. Tell the computer how to execute the file, this is done via the file ending on Windows and via the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on Unix systems

Now, that we have coverd the basics, We can look at how to create the file.
since you say, you're files are very similar you should create a template for your file.

This can be done using a Docstring, or a separate file, it is important however, that you replace all positions in the file, where you want a custom value by `{}`.

Using this template you can use the [format mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) inorder to generate your file.

In python pseudo-code this will look like this:

```
template = """#/bin/bash/ \n My template with {} specification and {} specification"""
spec_1 = "example"
spec_2 = "present"
with open('my_batch_file', 'w') as file:
    file.write(template.format(spec_1, spec_2))
```

Comment: Thanks. I will do the same

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: os version- windows 10